# How to use mocks in ng-apimock?

Tags: javascript

I have added ng-apimock to our Angular project.
I already have a mock definition like this:

```
 {
  "expression": "MyServiceEndpoint",
  "method": "GET",
  "name": "Edit",
  "isArray": false,
  "responses": {
    "default": {
      "default": true,
      "status": 200,
      "headers": {},
      "data": {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "some text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am reading documentation https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock. But i cannot understand how to use use written mocks.Where to connect the mocks file?

Comment: There has everything in the docs. What and where are you confused with?

Comment: How to connect the layout (json file) for the server being started

Comment: "src": "test/mocks"'?

Comment: you'll require that file

Comment: is it folder with mocks or file?

Comment: file path - where you define.

Comment: In which file that "src": "test/mocks"' needs to be added  and exactly where ? Also, is the path relative to this file itself?  I'm using the new l modular version, core + protractor plugin.   I'm with @ts-alan, docs are not straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my answer to this question -

[Mocking and Stubbing with protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056349/mocking-and-stubbing-with-protractor/67148935#67148935)

Here, I've explained all the configuration that I needed to do in detail. After configuring a mock server, you can use the API in the e2e test cases. Have given example usages in the linked answer.